# iOS development certificate and provisioning profile, possible without internet on the Mac?

Tags: ios, certificate

I have enrolled in the iOS developer's program. I've developed an app which I would like to test on an iPad device. For security reasons, I cannot have a direct internet connection on the Mac I am developing in.
I understand I can generate the certificate signing request and transfer it to another computer (this computer can have an internet connection), then upload it to the apple website. This is where the tricky part comes: the developer certificate will be pending, until I download the WWDR intermediate certificate and install it on the Mac without internet. Then after I refresh the page nothing happens, of course, because the Mac in which I registered the WWDR has no way of communicating with apple.
Is there another way of obtaining this certificate, or is there a method I could use, other than connecting the Mac to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overcome this problem, you need to share certificates for multiple device. You can easily export certificates from **/Applications/Utilities/Keychain** Access in **.p12** format & install that to other computer & after that you can sync all provisional, Adhoc & App Store profiles.

You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.theevilboss.com/2009/06/iphone-sdk-development-on-multiple.html) and these [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057644/developing-for-ios-on-multiple-computers-testing-on-a-single-device-advice) for step by step process.

Comment: I guess using this method with another Mac computer as an intermediate solves the issue.